# How to consum an AWS Api methodes from ASP.net client

Tags: asp.net

What are the steps to call an API hosted on AWS.
I have an ASP.net application that requires to call an AWS API. Do I need to use the AWS's SDK or use HTTPS calls to the AWS.

Comment: You can use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient)

Comment: Thank you Wael for the response. That is my current implementation but when I read on AWS documentation, it references the AWS SDK. I am not sure if I need to use the AWS SDK or just use the HTTPClient and deal with the JWT token header. How to generated it?

Comment: Can you share more details about the AWS API you want to use

Comment: it is an WebAPI which provide services and hosted on AWS cloud.

Comment: If it's your WebAPI so once you publish you can call it directly, Did you tried something in your owns and have issues?

Comment: No it is not and I am thinking the same way..., It is a WebAPI regardless of who the publisher or owner is. It should be access able through HTTPS action verbs. But The AWS documentation does not directly say that and they keep prompting their SDK.